# Install package into custom directory Composer

Tags: path, installation, package, composer-php

Hey I am trying to install a package into a custom 'admin' directory using composer.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "name": "frontier/installer",
  "description": "The best front end engineer package around",
  "require": {
    "aheinze/cockpit": "*"
  },
  "extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "admin": ["aheinze/cockpit"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run composer install it all installs but defaults to vendor/aheinze/cockpit I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Have done my research this should be the right code... any obvious errors?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the `installer-paths` option the package you want to be installed in a different path **must** require `composer/installers`.

In your case the `aheinze/cockpit` package doesn't require `composer/installers` as you can see in its [`composer.json` at github](https://github.com/aheinze/cockpit/blob/master/composer.json).

Have a look at the [composer documentation for custom paths](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) and you see that it tells you:

> **Note:** You cannot use this to change the path of any package. This is only applicable to packages that require `composer/installers` and use a custom type that it handles.

This means you are not able to change the install path of this specific package.
Anyway I don't see any necessity to install it into any different directory from the default `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 7):

I have implemented this composer plugin to install packages into user (custom) defined folders you can just include it in your composer.json, follow the example and tell me if you have more questions :)

https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer

## composer-custom-directory-installer

A composer plugin, to install differenty types of composer packages in custom directories outside the default composer default installation path which is in the `vendor` folder.

This is not another `composer-installer` library for supporting non-composer package types i.e. `application` .. etc. This is only to add the flexability of installing composer packages outside the vendor folder. This package only supports `composer` package types,

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type

> The type of the package. It defaults to library.
>
> Package types are used for custom installation logic. If you have a package that needs some special logic, you can define a custom type. This could be a symfony-bundle, a wordpress-plugin or a typo3-module. These types will all be specific to certain projects, and they will need to provide an installer capable of installing packages of that type.

### How to use

- Include the composer plugin into your `composer.json` `require` section::

```json
"require":{
    "php": ">=5.3",
    "mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer": "1.1.*",
    "monolog/monolog": "*"
  }
```

- In the `extra` section define the custom directory you want to the package to be installed in::

```json
  "extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "./monolog/": ["monolog/monolog"]
    }
```

by adding the `installer-paths` part, you are telling composer to install the `monolog` package inside the `monolog` folder in your root directory.

- As an added new feature, we have added more flexibility in defining your download directory same like the `composer/installers`, in other words you can use variables like `{$vendor}` and `{$name}` in your `installer-path` section:

```json
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "./customlibs/{$vendor}/db/{$name}": ["doctrine/orm"]
    }
}
```

the above will manage to install the `doctrine/orm` package in the root folder of your project, under `customlibs`.

### Note

Composer `type: project` is not supported in this installer, as packages with type `project` only make sense to be used with application shells like `symfony/framework-standard-edition`, to be required by another package.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to put all packages under the "admin" directory, the best option is:

```
{
  "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "admin"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `post-autoload-dump` script to copy the package after install/dump-autoload:

```
"scripts": {
  "post-autoload-dump": [
    "cp -r vendor/aheinze/cockpit admin"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For install multiple packages in the same directory you can follow this structure

1- your path should be like this `"modules/patched/{$name}"`

2- and an array of any package that you want to move or install that same directory

```
"extra":{
    "installer-paths": {

        "modules/patched/{$name}": [
            "drupal/signature_field",
            "drupal/eck",
            "drupal/auto_entitylabel"
        ]

    }
```

The package or module should be in your require section as well.

```
"require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/signature_field": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/eck": "^1.0@alpha",
}
```