# In TYPO3 8.7, require a non-extension package in custom extension's composer.json

Tags: ckeditor, composer-php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to require a package for `rte_ckeditor` within a custom local TYPO3 extension. I see that I [should be able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984996/install-package-into-custom-directory-composer) to use `installer-paths` but noticed that the `#typo3-cms-composer` Slack channel mentioned that it doesn't play well with TYPO3.

Here's what I want to do in my extension's `composer.json` file but it seems to be ignored when I run `composer install`:

```
"require": {
  "w8tcha/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin": "~1.17"
},
"extra": {
  "installer-paths": {
    "./Resources/Public/RTE/Wordcount/": [
      "w8tcha/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `installer-paths` option belongs to the [`composer/installers`](https://packagist.org/packages/composer/installers) package. However, you cannot use this package since it conflicts with [`typo3/cms-composer-installers`](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-composer-installers).

Even though there is a Composer package for the CKEditor wordcount plugin you should install [`ckeditor-wordcount-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin) via NPM instead. Depending on your build tools you can then copy that package to your desired location, e.g. via Grunt and [`grunt-npmcopy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-npmcopy).

Comment: Okay, thanks that's a helpful answer and gives me an alternative, we're using npm. Do you know if the `typo3/cms-composer-installers` conflict going to just keep propagating with future TYPO3 releases or is there a plan to use it in different way in the future at some point?

Comment: Actually I'll be using webpack's `mix.copy` to copy the files to correct location from npm's `node_modules` folder.

Comment: The long term goal is to get rid of the `typo3/cms-composer-installers` package altogether but right now it serves as an essential part of TYPO3 Composer setups. Since it has all the specific knowledge `composer/installers` does not have, the conflict will stay for now.